# NaN giving ValueError in OneHotEncoder in scikit-learn

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

Here is my code

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

train = pd.DataFrame({
        'users':['John Johnson','John Smith','Mary Williams']
})
test = pd.DataFrame({
        'users':[None,np.nan,'John Smith','Mary Williams']
})

ohe = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False,handle_unknown='ignore')
ohe.fit(train)
train_transformed = ohe.fit_transform(train)

test_transformed = ohe.transform(test)
print(test_transformed)
```

I expected the OneHotEncoder to be able to handle the np.nan in the test dataset, since

```
handle_unknown='ignore'
```

But it gives ValueError. It is able to handle the None value though. Why is it failing?And how do I get around it (besides Imputer)?

From the documentation (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html)
it seemed that this was what handle_unknown is for.

Comment: double-posted: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58220511/10495893

Answer (score -1):

This option gives a solution when test set has unseen categorical value in train set. If you would put ‘steve stevenson’ in the test set it would not return an error, it would return column with all zeros.

```
    train = pd.DataFrame({
        'users':['John Johnson','John Smith','Mary Williams']
})
test = pd.DataFrame({
        'users':['John Smith','Mary Williams', 'Steve Stevenson']
})

ohe = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False, handle_unknown = 'ignore')
ohe.fit(train)

test_transformed = ohe.transform(test)
print(test_transformed)
```

Solution to None problem would be to replace None values with some category, like ‘unknown’.

Hope this helps