# How to handle missing values (NaN) in categorical data when using scikit-learn OneHotEncoder?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have recently started learning python to develop a predictive model for a research project using machine learning methods. I have a large dataset comprised of both numerical and categorical data. The dataset has lots of missing values. I am currently trying to encode the categorical features using OneHotEncoder. When I read about OneHotEncoder, my understanding was that for a missing value (NaN), OneHotEncoder would assign 0s to all the feature's categories, as such:

```
0     Male 
1     Female
2     NaN
```

After applying OneHotEncoder:

```
0     10 
1     01
2     00
```

However, when running the following code:

```py
    # Encoding categorical data
    from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
    from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder


    ct = ColumnTransformer([('encoder', OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore'), [1])],
                           remainder='passthrough')
    obj_df = np.array(ct.fit_transform(obj_df))
    print(obj_df)
```

I am getting the error **ValueError: Input contains NaN**

So I am guessing my previous understanding of how OneHotEncoder handles missing values is wrong. 
Is there a way for me to get the functionality described above? I know imputing the missing values before encoding will resolve this issue, but I am reluctant to do this as I am dealing with medical data and fear that imputation may decrease the predictive accuracy of my model.

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58222008/nan-giving-valueerror-in-onehotencoder-in-scikit-learn) that is similar but the answer doesn't offer a detailed enough solution on how to deal with the NaN values.

Let me know what your thoughts are, thanks.

Comment: Keep an eye on https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/11996.

Comment: Thank you @BenReiniger, good to know the developers agree OneHotEncoder should handle missing values! :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You will need to impute the missing values before. You can define a [`Pipeline`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html) with an imputing step using [`SimpleImputer`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.impute.SimpleImputer.html) setting a `constant` strategy to input a new category for null fields, prior to the OneHot encoding:

```
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
import numpy as np

categorical_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='constant', fill_value='missing')),
    ('encoder', OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore'))])

preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        ('cat', categorical_transformer, [0])
    ])
```

---

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['Male', 'Female', np.nan])
preprocessor.fit_transform(df)
array([[0., 1., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1.]])
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the helpful code. Do you think imputing using the most frequent value in the column will not compromise the predictive accuracy of the model?

Comment: This is quite a common strategy for categorical data. Its not ideal but you do have missing data afterall. Though in the cases where there isn't too much missing data it is a reasonable approach @sums

Comment: It is, I have been searching for alternatives though to see if I could get around manipulating the data too much. Unfortunately, I have quite a lot of missing data. I may have to resort to his method though. Thanks for the input.

Comment: I would suggest using `strategy='constant'`, `fill_value='missing'` to preserve the categories' structure, rather than imputing with the most frequent.

Comment: @BenReiniger does this mean I will have an additional category after encoding that will be the 'missing' category? And if so, do you suggest I then delete the 'missing' category from all encoded features (similar to the answer posted by Om Rastogi) or leave it?

Comment: @sums22, that depends on your subsequent modeling I think.  Personally: if you need to avoid multicolinearity, then drop it; and otherwise, keep it.

Answer (score 8):

From version 0.24, `OneHotEncoder` now just treats missing values as its own category.  [What's New entry](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/whats_new/v0.24.html#id14).

Answer (score 6):

1. Change the **NaN values with "Others"**.
2. Then proceed with one-hot encoding
3. You can then remove the "Others" column.

Answer (score 1):

One option here would be to use pandas `get_dummies()` function documented [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html). The `dummy_na` parameter can be altered to include NaN as a separate category. Based on your desired solution, seems like the default value will do.

```
obj_df_encoded = pd.get_dummies(obj_df)
print(obj_df)
>> 1 0
>> 0 1
>> 0 0
```

If using Scikit-Learn's One Hot Encoder is necessary, you can fill nan values with pandas `filna('something')`, one hot encode this as a new category, then remove this column after.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I was searching for the same thing and I found answers that were given to your question, but none of them much helped except @Om Rastogi's.
But later, I found a simpler approach, so I'm posting both approaches here.

> > > #### 1. Long One : Let's say I have a Dataframe, that consists of Nan values.

```
new_df.fillna("Others",inplace=True,axis = 1)

new_df = pd.get_dummies(new_df, columns=cat_col)

col_to_drop = [col for col in new_df.columns.tolist() if col.__contains__("Others")]

new_df.drop(col_to_drop, axis=1,inplace=True)
```

> > > #### 2. Short one: Just adding a parameter can save you a lot of work.

```
cat_col = data.dtypes[data.dtypes == 'O'].index.tolist() #to get the list of categorical variables

new_df = pd.get_dummies(new_df, columns=cat_col, drop_first=True,dummy_na=True)
```

Hope you're satisfied with my answer, you can upvote this answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. Change the NaN values with "Others".
2. Then proceed with one-hot encoding
3. You can then remove the "Others" column.

Answer (score 0):

OneHotEncoder adds missing values as new column.  You can prevent the creation of this potentially useless column by setting the categories manually (as shown below) or by using the 'drop' parameter of OneHotEncoder.  This encoder will give you the outputs you illustrated:

```
enc = OneHotEncoder(categories = [[0, 1]], handle_unknown='ignore')
```

Answer (score -1):

As far as I understood after a long time of dealing with this problem, the problem is because in the split of the training test set you have some columns with the same value for all data samples. If your data rows that are saved close to each other are more similar, then it is more likely that would happen. Shuffling data can help in this case. This seems a bug with scikit. I'm using version `0.23.2` version.