# Missing categorical data should be encoded with an all-zero one-hot vector

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science

I am working on a machine learning project with very sparsely labeled data. There are several categorical features, resulting in roughly one hundred different classes between the features.

For example:

```
0    red
1    blue
2    <missing>

color_cat = pd.DataFrame(['red', 'blue', np.NAN])
color_enc = OneHotEncoder(sparse=True, handle_unknown='ignore')
color_one_hot = color_enc.fit_transform(color_cat)
```

After I put these through scikit's `OneHotEncoder` I am expecting the missing data to be encoded as `00`, since the docs state that `handle_unknown='ignore'` causes the encoder to return an all zero array. Substituting another value, such as with `[SimpleImputer][1]` is not an option for me.

What I expect:

```
0    10
1    01
2    00
```

Instead `OneHotEncoder` treats the missing values as another category.

What I get:

```
0    100
1    010
2    001
```

I have seen the related question: [How to handle missing values (NaN) in categorical data when using scikit-learn OneHotEncoder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62409303/how-to-handle-missing-values-nan-in-categorical-data-when-using-scikit-learn-o)
But the solutions do not work for me. I explicitly require a zero vector.

Comment: just replace nan with 'unknown' then labelencoder fit_transform your dataframe category column or use pd.get_dummies

Comment: See also the `category_encoders` package version of `OneHotEncoder`, which has the option `handle_missing='value'` to do what you want.  https://contrib.scikit-learn.org/category_encoders/onehot.html

Comment: Also an interesting solution, but I didn't want to install another library just for one function. But noted for the future! Thank you, Ben.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never really worked with sparse matrix, but one way is to remove the column corresponding to your `nan` value. Get the `categories_` from your model and create a Boolean mask where is it not `nan` (I use `pd.Series.notna` but probably other way) and create a new (or reassign) sparse matrix. Basically add to your code:

```
# currently you have
color_one_hot
# <3x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
#   with 3 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

# line of code to add
new_color_one_hot = color_one_hot[:,pd.Series(color_enc.categories_[0]).notna().to_numpy()]

# and now you have
new_color_one_hot
# <3x2 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
#   with 2 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

# and
new_color_one_hot.todense()
# matrix([[0., 1.],
#         [1., 0.],
#         [0., 0.]])
```

Edit: also `get_dummies` kind of gives similar result `pd.get_dummies(color_cat[0], sparse=True)`

EDIT: After looking a bit more you can specify the parameter `categories` in `OneHotEncoder` so if you do:

```
color_cat = pd.DataFrame(['red', 'blue', np.nan])
color_enc = OneHotEncoder(categories=[color_cat[0].dropna().unique()],  ## here
                          sparse=True, handle_unknown='ignore')
color_one_hot = color_enc.fit_transform(color_cat)
color_one_hot.todense()
# matrix([[1., 0.],
#         [0., 1.],
#         [0., 0.]])
```

Comment: Indeed, for me the point is that *unknown categories* are those which were not present at fitting time, while being present during transformation. The manual specification of `categories` allows for the definition of the categories to be considered during fitting.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I had encoded my labels by integer, which introduced the additional hiccup of requiring a _sorted_ array for the categories.